# amplify push error "Only one CloudFormation template is allowed in the resource directory"

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have added, pushed amplify auth in react app, it worked fine.
After this I added function and trying to push it, its giving me error:-

```
Only one CloudFormation template is allowed in the resource directory
```

can you please help me resolving it.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing when trying to create a new function, was working fine before. Did you find a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3775) has been fixed in [amplify/cli version 4.17.2](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/packages/amplify-cli/CHANGELOG.md#4172-2020-03-26). Simply update to that version and the error will go away.